# Automatically Remove System.debug statements from Apex Code?

Tags: apex, debug

We normally come into situation that, before production deployment we need to remove system.debug('*****');  statements from the code.

I am wondering if there any existing tool is available for such requirement where instead of doing manual work I can remove these statements automatically! or if I have to build this functionality will Tooling API would be the best approach to get started with? as I would need to parse the apex, identify the instances in code where system.debug exist and then do the necessary operation to replace it.

Answer (score 4):

Using **sublime text** you can use the feature

> Find > find in files (CTRL+Shift+F)

Activate regular expression by clicking the button `.*`

Search for `System.debug(.*)`  and replace it with an empty string

[image: Capture]

*Customize the where clause to target the file extensions you want*

Answer (score 3):

Removing debugs logs would be pain, if you perform search and replace in your editor, it would not be efficient.

Better and easier option would be to create ​a utility method for logging your debug statements. 
Control it with custom settings.

By that you can enable it back when something goes wrong.

Answer (score 2):

In VS Code, you do this:

1. Open Search (Ctrl + Shift + F)
2. Click the `.*` icon to activate Regular Expression evaluation
3. In the Search box, enter `System.debug((.|\n)*?);\n`, like so:

[image]

4. This should bring up all instances where `System.debug(***any code here***);` is invoked and followed by a newline character.  You can view all these instances and replace them one by one, or use the icon next to the Replace box to replace them all en masse.

Note: the above Regular Expression works on both single- and multi-line debug statements, and removes the line entirely.

Another note: if your code contains trailing white space, you may need to apply some formatting after running this.  This is most easily accomplished if you're using the [Prettier Apex plugin](https://github.com/dangmai/prettier-plugin-apex).

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I think a good tool for this kind of text manipulation is sed. If you navigate to your classes directory, this command should replace all system.debug() statements with a dummy variable assignment.

```
$ sed -i 's/system\.debug(.*);/Integer ThisVariableNameIsProbablyNotAlreadyBeingUsed = 3;/g' *
```

I would suggest you not simply rip out those statement, and replace them with a dummy expression instead because you could change the behavior of you code if, for example, you have a for loop followed directly by a debug statement rather than a code block.

```
for (...) system.debug(...);
... something that shouldn't be looped ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I will revive this thread and suggest a great framework that allows better control over logging and debugging as Raul proposed.

https://github.com/j-fischer/rflib/wiki

**Key Features**

**Logging Framework (package RFLIB):**

- Logger for LWC and Aura, which publishes logs the same way as Apex
  Configuration through Custom Settings allowing for different log
  configurations between users
- Aggregation of log statements when
  reporting
- Using Platform Events for reporting of log statements
- Support Batched Logging for when DML statements are not supported
- Log Archive using Big Objects
- Dashboard for all Object and Field permissions for Profiles and Permission Sets
- Supports logging in Flow and Process Builder Supports
- Salesforce Functions (NodeJS only)

**Feature Switches (package RFLIB-FS):**

- Fully configured using Custom Metadata
- Supports hierarchical structure (similar to Custom Settings) to override settings at the profile or user level
- Fully supported in Flow Builder through Get Records or Apex Action

**Trigger Framework (package RFLIB-TF):**

- Fully decoupled framework, trigger handlers work in isolation
- Recursion tracking to allow for easy prevention of multiple executions
- Fully configurable trigger management (activation, order, error handling, etc) using Custom Metadata